Programmatically define dropdown items in microsoft forms?
I have been looking into a problem for my organization who is trying to save money on licensing costs. I have what I think should be a relatively simple problem where I use Power Automate to programmatically populate the items of a dropdown list in a Microsoft Forms question. This is a simple problem if I could use Power Apps or Power Pages. These options are not available to me.
After reading on the web, it seems there might be a way to use the Microsoft Graph API to call the JSON code for an entire form and then define a custom function to modify it and then update it with via MS Graph. However, I am not sure that this will work.
Before I ask my organization for additional permissions to play around with this problem, I was hoping that somebody with more experience in this domain might tell me if it is possible and/or point me in the right direction.
I have done some research and looked into what my other free options are. MS Graphs seems to be the way, but I will also need to ask for (a lot of) additional access and I want to justify my request by having a better idea as to whether what I am trying to accomplish is do-able.
Thank you for your time.
I tried using power apps (successfully) but my company doesn't want to pay for it.

I don't think there is a Microsoft graph api that allows you to modify the structure of a Microsoft form.   If you don't want to use Power Apps you could create your own custom SPFx Web Part and then embed it in a SharePoint page.  here is the tutorial provided by Microsoft on creating your first SPFx WebPart. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part. When you are first playing around sometimes it is easier to set up your own Developer Office 365 Tenant so you have all the admin rights to see if what you are trying is going to work for you.  https://danusher.com/how-do-i-cloud/how-to-create-a-microsoft-365-developer-tenant/
one other option. as you are probably aware the Office 365 SharePoint no longer allows you to create JavaScript scripts.  but if you are allowed you can install this webpart.  https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-script-editor  that will allow you to create JavaScript apps directly inside your SharePoint page.  and you could use that to design your form, including your dynamic drop down, directly in a SharePoint Page.
